# Unsupported x86-64 instruction set error when compiling C file

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

I am trying to follow the tutorials in [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/664165/Writing-a-boot-loader-in-Assembly-and-C-Part) link.

When I get down to the part where I start making a test.c file, I try to run the first compilation line.

```
gcc -c -g -Os -march=i686 -ffreestanding -Wall -Werror test.c -o test.o
```

Here is the contents of `test.c`

```
__asm__(".code16\n");
__asm__("jmpl $0x0000, $main\n");

void main() {
}
```

When I call the first compilation line, it shows me this error.

```
test.c:1:0: error: CPU you selected does not support x86-64 instruction set
 __asm__(".code16\n");
 ^
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? And if possible, how to fix it?

I am running Ubuntu Desktop x64, thank you in advance for your help.

EDIT:

I have changed the first compilation line to:

```
gcc -c -g -Os -m32 -ffreestanding -Wall -Werror test.c -o test.o
```

And it seems to work fine. However, there are two more lines that are giving me trouble.

```
ld -static -Ttest.ld -nostdlib --nmagic -o test.elf test.o
```

and

```
objcopy -O binary test.elf test.bin
```

The first one throws me the error of.

```
ld: i386 architecture of input file `test.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
```

And because of this, I have not tried the final line of compilation.

Here is the code for the test.ld file.

```
ENTRY(main);
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x7C00;
    .text : AT(0x7C00)
    {
        *(.text);
    }
    .sig : AT(0x7DFE)
    {
        SHORT(0xaa55);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: ` .code16 ' or ` .code16gcc ' directive before the assembly language instructions is used to run in 16-bit mode.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Supply `-m32` instead of `-march=i686`.

Comment: I did this and it works, however there are two more lines of compilation that are given in the tutorial. The second line 'ld -static -Ttest.ld -nostdlib --nmagic -o test.elf test.o' gives me the error of 'ld: i386 architecture of input file `test.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output'. I've made the edit's to the question with the ld code for you to see

Comment: Supply `-melf_i386` to the `ld` invocation.

Answer (score 7):

in fact **add** `-m32`  you can keep -march=i686 ...

```
gcc -c -g -Os -march=i686 -m32 -ffreestanding -Wall -Werror test.c -o test.o
```

works

```
gcc -c -g -Os -march=i686 -m16 -ffreestanding -Wall -Werror test.c -o test.o
```

works

```
gcc -c -g -Os -march=i686 -m64 -ffreestanding -Wall -Werror test.c -o test.o
```

fails with ;

> test.c:1:0: error: CPU you selected does not support x86-64
>   instruction set  **asm**(".code16\n");

Answer (score -2):

```
gcc -std=c99 -c -g -Os -march=i686 -m32 -ffreestanding -Wall -Werror test.c -o test.o
ld -static -T test.ld -m elf_i386 -nostdlib --nmagic -o test.elf test.o
```

Comment: This answer doesn't add anything new.  It seems to be an attempt to summarize all the advice in the other answers.